# Is it practical to live in Stockholm's inner city while studying in Kista?

Tags: public-transport, accommodation, sweden, stockholm

I am looking for a place to stay in Stockholm.
Question is, where should I look?

I want to be near enough to the University (in Kista) to study yet near enough to the inner city to go out and stuff. So, does anybody know if it is practical to look for a place in say Sundbyberg and travel in both directions by Tunnelbana?

Comment: I think this is more a living issue than a travel issue. I think this is off-topic.

Comment: This is probably not even on-topic for [the Immigration Stack Exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10331/immigration), but you might be interested in taking a look at it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, the commute looks ok to me.

The [Stockholm Journey Planner](http://reseplanerare.sl.se/) gives travel times of about 19-23 minutes from Sundbyberg.

[image]

I used Sundbyberg centrum and Isafjordsgatan 39 (where [SU's DSV](http://dsv.su.se/) is located, with other universities like [KTH](http://www.kth.se/ict) very close by). Try it for yourself using the exact address of your campus.

In fact, we're talking of a distance of about **6 kilometers**, so your best bet—at least when it's warm outside—may well be **bicycle**. (Most likely it's less than 6 km by bike, as I imagine you can cut through the forests/fields near Ursvik.) If you're going to be studying there for a while, buying a cheap bike makes sense.